# URL rewrite (rewrite rule) in grails

Tags: grails

How to set url rewrite mechanism in groovy grails? Please let me know by step by step. Please help me.

Have used this is grails? This works similar to htaccess. They have a comparison on this. So, think, we should be able to write a generic rule, for the redirects. Could you please check and see.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
"/**-spid-$PROP_ID" { //Property Details Page
        namespace = "propertydetails"
        controller = "Desktop"
        action = "show"
        constraints {
            PROP_ID(nullable: false, blank: false, validator: { val, obj ->
                if (!(PdValidatorUtil.ValidatePropId(val))) {
                    return false
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

I have used the above url mappings in my code. It represents for url of type **www.aaa.com/washington-spid-per4566** it should call **show** method of **DesktopController** in **propertyDetails** namespace.Under constraints i specify the contraints on my propid variable i.e. format kinda things. follow the below links for references.

http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Plug-ins/URL%20mappings.html
http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2013/11/grails-goodness-grouping-url-mappings.html